# Error with CString when I import into VC++2005?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc, visual-c++-6, visual-c++-2005

I wrote code in VC++6.0 and imported it into VC++2005.
I get an ambiguous error with the unicode insertion now?

```
CString s;

s.Format("%f\r\n", (double)timebTime.time + (double)timebTime.millitm / 1000);
s+="RAMP,"; 
s+=0x00b5;  // <-- Error: VC++(2005):  "error C2593: 'operator +=' is ambiguous"
s+="m";
```

Comment: That is a thing from _MFC_, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that VC++6.0's default compilation model is ANSI/MBCS (i.e. `TCHAR` is a `char`, `CString` is a sequence of `char`'s, etc.), instead VC++2005's default compilation model is **Unicode** (i.e. `TCHAR` is `wchar_t`, `CString` is actually a `CStringW`, i.e. a `wchar_t` string).

I'd just use the Unicode model (don't bother with ANSI/MBCS compatibility and `TCHAR`, `_T("...")`, etc.), and adjust your code like this:

```
static const wchar_t microSign = 0x00B5;

CString s;  
s.Format(L"%f\r\n", 
    static_cast<double>(timebTime.time) +
    static_cast<double>(timebTime.millitm) / 1000.0);
s += L"RAMP,"; 
s += microSign;
s += L"m";
```

Note that the use of a named constant (like `microSign`) makes the code more readable than a *"magic number"* like `0x00B5`.

Moreover, I'd store the format string (including the "`RAMP,µm`" part) in the app resources and load it from there instead of building it in the source code.